# How do i make a discord bot send a message when a specific user is mentioned?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm fairly new to javascript and have been using Discord.js to make one or two Discord Bots. I'm working on a feature that sends a message when I'm pinged in my discord server. I've tried a few things and none have worked.

I have this so far, it detects when any user is pinged, not just me.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
  message.channel.send('Do not ping this user.');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can compare User IDs. [How to get User IDs.](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-)

```js
if (message.mentions.users.first().id === 'Your ID') // if the person mentioned was you
 return message.channel.send('Do not mention this user');
```

---

Furthermore, as the name suggests, [`Collection.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) will fetch the first element of a collection. This means that the `if` statement will only return true if the *first* mention was you. For example:

```js
User: 'Hello @you' // detected
User: 'Hello @notYou and @you' // not detected
```

To circumvent this, you can use [`Collection.has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=has):

```js
// will return true if *any* of the mentions were you
if (message.mentions.users.has('Your ID'))
 return message.channel.send('Do not mention this user');
```